# Updating extensions/vendor

Tags: yii2, yii2-user

I'm trying to update vendor, specifically yii2-user. I'm using command on my root yii2 advanced folder

```
composer update
```

But it doesn't update my yii2-user vendor. Not sure how to update it.

Comment: Provide more detail about your composer.json file and how you are adding ```yii2-user```in your dependencies. May be you need to use ```composer install```but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the dektrium extension

```
composer install "dektrium/yii2-user": "0.9.*@dev"
```